# Combine objects in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a react state with these two objects where one is an array and another is object

```
DumpNames = [], {ActiveTab: '0'}
```

So if I put array object in setState as

```
this.setState({DumpNames})
```

Then it will create `key-value` pair with `DumpNames : []`.

How do I combine `ActiveTab` object along with `DumpNames`.

i.e. I want to do something like

```
this.setState({DumpNames,{ActiveTab}})
```

However If I try to put both these objects in an array and then destruct then it works fine.

```
 let myObjects = [{DumpNames : DumpNames, ActiveTab : ActiveTab}]
 this.setState(...myObjects)
```

Is there any other way I can accomplish this rather than destructing this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your last example

```
let myObjects = [{DumpNames : DumpNames, ActiveTab : ActiveTab}]
this.setState(...myObjects)
```

You're destructuring the array. So that's equal to:

```
this.setState({ DumpNames, ActiveTab });
```

This uses the [object literal property value shorthand](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand), so the above is equal to:

```
this.setState({
  DumpNames: DumpNames,
  ActiveTab: ActiveTab
});
```

So maybe you could define your component state like this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      DumpNames: [],
      ActiveTab: '0',
    };
  }

  ...
}
```

You can then modify the state with either key:

```
this.setState({ DumpNames: ['John', 'Doe'] })
```

or

```
this.setState({ ActiveTab: '1' })
```

or

```
this.setState({ DumpNames: ['Hello', 'Bye'], ActiveTab: '3' })
```

or

```
this.setState({ DumpNames, ActiveTab: '3' });
```

Comment: There isn't anything to imply that the OP would have put the setState function inside the render function

Comment: @BlakeSteel The subject of matter is setting the state. The question implies that the OP is relatively new to this subject, so it could be worth mentioning to help.

Comment: @Alserda, You see `this.setState({DumpNames})` this is how  I am putting it in the  state. My question was how to put `ActiveState` along side this object. I am totally aware of re-rendering. None of your statements I found worthy. Since I am looking out something like `DumpNames`  without key-value pair and `ActiveState` with key-value pair in one `setState` method

Comment: @user10005648 this.setState({ DumpNames, ActiveTab: 3 });